# How can I clear the 'Previous Pictures' menu in Choose A Desktop Background?

Tags: windows-8

When you select a wallpaper it has a list of previous locations where wallpaper was selected. How can I clear this list (is there a registry key or something?).

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

The picture location history is stored in the registry in an encrypted form. To clear previous locations, follow the steps below.

1. Select any wallpaper from the default picture locations:

   - **Windows Desktop Backgrounds**
   - **Pictures Library**
   - **Top Rated Photos**
   - **Solid Colors**

   **Note** If you want to preserve the location corresponding to the current background picture (in case it's stored in a custom path), skip this step.
2. Open a [command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-8), type or paste the following command, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   reg delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Wallpapers\Images" /va /f
   ```

### References

- [How to Remove the Desktop Background Picture Location History in Windows 7 and Windows 8](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/70606-desktop-background-remove-picture-location-history.html)